# Adding Buttons with Functionality Using JavaScript in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a modal window below to have customized buttons and functionality attached to those buttons using jQuery-UI. However, I want to do the equivalent in Bootstrap using JavaScript and not using data attributes. How would I do this? The [Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) only gives the example of doing something like this using data attributes.

```
function showWindow(message) {
    windowShowing = true;
    $("#alertWindow").dialog(
    {
        height: 120, 
        modal: true, 
        buttons: 
        { 
          Continue: function(){$(this).dialog("close"); someProcedure();},            
          Exit: function(){$(this).dialog("close"); exitProcedure();}
        },
        close: function(){windowShowing = false;}       
     });
    $("#alertWindowMsg").text(message);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add separate handlers and use the modal methods provided by Bootstrap. Something like

```
$(".close-button").click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    exitProcedure();
});

$(".continue-button").click(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    continueProcedure();
});
```

Comment: Are you saying that I need to define these modal buttons in the HTML?

Comment: @FearlessFuture Yes, you can put those buttons inside the html of your modal and then add these handlers into your javascript.